# Reference an object using string (the object is under the tab control)

Tags: vb.net, loops, object, textbox

I have a working code here that can put `test` to all textboxes from 1 to 10. The name of the textboxes are Tb_Hour_1, Tb_Hour_2, Tb_Hour_3, Tb_Hour_4, etc. up to 10.

```
Dim textboxes As TextBox

For i As Integer = 1 To 10
  textboxes = Me.Controls("TB_Hour_" & i)
  textboxes.Text = "Test" & i
Next
```

But the problem comes in when I put my text boxes under the tab control, by searching I've found out that by adding `in` I can specify the place of the object that I want to call. Here's the working code.

```
For Each c As TextBox In TabPage1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
   If c.Text = String.Empty Then c.Text = "a"
Next
```

My question is how can I integrate the 2 codes so I can have something like this

```
    Dim textboxes As TextBox In TabPage1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()

    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        textboxes = Me.Controls("TB_Hour_" & i)
        textboxes.Text = "Test" & i
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

My VB is a little rusty, but it should be something like this. You can loop through all of the controls on the tab, look for ones that starts with "`TB_Hour_"`, cast it to a textbox and do whatever it is you want to do.

```
For Each c As Control In TabPage1.Controls
   If c.Name.StartsWith("TB_Hour_") Then
       ' it's a textbox
        Dim tb as Textbox = DirectCast(c, Textbox)
        ' do whatever you're going to do
   End If
Next
```

Comment: I tried to add this code `tb.Text = "a"` at the `' do whatever you're going to do` but nothing happens. :(

Comment: @CaryBondoc do you have any other code that could be clearing the textbox afterward.

Comment: Thanks for your response, no Sir. I recreated it so there are no other codes other than the one you provide.

Comment: @CaryBondoc Try calling .Refresh() on the textbox.

Comment: still not working Sir. :( Can you edit the code to output some text? Maybe I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: @CaryBondoc I don't have visual studio at home or I would. That looks like it should work, though.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Unfortunately I can't make your code to work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you tucked the `TextBox`es into a `TabContol`, don't use `Me.Controls()`.  Instead try:

```
Dim textboxes As TextBox

For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    textboxes = TabPage1.Controls("TB_Hour_" & i)
    textboxes.Text = "Test" & i
Next
```

Otherwise, you can do something like:

```
Dim textboxes As TextBox

For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    textboxes = Me.TabControl1.Controls("TabPage1").Controls("TextBox" & i)
    textboxes.Text = "Test" & i
Next
```